# Subnets to AZs and repeat

Tags: terraform

I want to build a 3 tier VPC using only AZ1a and AZ1b. But I want to have a range of IP addresses and use them for each tier but need them to always fall in AZ1a or AZ1b.

I have 3 app tiers (web, app, db):

Using only two AZs.

```
availability_zones = ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b"]
```

I have put together a list of the subnets I want to use. SoI want web to grab the first two and put into each of the AZs, then I want app to grab the next two and put into each of the AZs, and so on on.

```
private_subnets_cidr_intapp = ["10.211.130.0/28", "10.211.130.16/28", "10.211.130.32", "10.211.130.48", "10.211.130.64/28", "10.211.130.80/28"]
```

How do you go about this, and an example would help. Should I be using a map?

Comment: Could you please provide the entire code snippet?

Comment: What pieces of code? Resource area needing to see?

Comment: Yes, please. It would be better to provide the exact solution what you are looking for